# Create temp table from another temp table in Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to create #temp table from another #temp table then it's through the error.

```
 Set @Query = 'Select Work_Order_No,ServiceCode,StageNo,ItemWeight,StagePercentage,FebLocation 
    INTO #TempMaster
    FROM #Temp '
EXEC(@Query)
```

Above query throw the error

```
Invalid object name '#TempMaster'.
```

and if I execute this query

```
Set   @Query = 'Select Work_Order_No,ServiceCode,StageNo,ItemWeight,StagePercentage,FebLocation 
    INTO ##TempMaster
    FROM #Temp '

EXEC(@Query)
```

Then it's working fine. What is different between these two statement. What is reason that first query throw error and second query run successfully.

Comment: The code you posted does **not** throw that error [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15016). Maybe the error was coming from another line you haven't shown us.

Comment: First query throw the error and second one execute successfully

Comment: both query running fine

Comment: Sorry to all I update the query

Comment: So it is not the dynamic query execution that throws the error, right? The problem happens *after* `EXEC(@Query)`, specifically when you are attempting to read from the table specified in the dynamic query's `INTO` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Following the edit the difference is that local `#temp` tables created in a child scope are automatically dropped when the scope exits and are not visible to the parent scope. `##` prefixed tables are global temporary tables and not dropped automatically when the scope exits. Instead they are dropped when the creating connection is closed and no other connection is currently accessing it.

There is no apparent requirement to use `EXEC` here anyway so you could avoid this issue by using the code you originally posted.

```
SELECT Work_Order_No,
       ServiceCode,
       StageNo,
       ItemWeight,
       StagePercentage,
       FebLocation
INTO   #TempMaster
FROM   #Temp
```

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi - Well in that case you need a global `##temp` table then as the local one you create in the child scope will be automatically dropped. Or you need to add all code using the table to the same child scope dynamic query. It is actually possible to create a local `#temp` table in the parent scope then `ALTER` in a child scope but that is very messy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = '
IF OBJECT_ID (N''tempdb.dbo.##TempMaster'') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE ##TempMaster

SELECT Work_Order_No,ServiceCode,StageNo,ItemWeight,StagePercentage,FebLocation 
INTO ##TempMaster
FROM #Temp'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: My ##TempMaster working fine I just want to know why #TempMaster throw error

Comment: Please see @Martin Smith's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
set @Query = 'select Work_Order_No,ServiceCode,StageNo,ItemWeight,StagePercentage,FebLocation 
INTO #TempMaster1
FROM tablename

select * into #t from #TempMaster1

drop table #TempMaster1
drop table #t '

exec (@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create #temp table inside dynamic query it is only valid inside that dynamic query and you can not use it later after dynamic query has finished executing.

If you really need to fill your table dynamically - you should create it up front.